# How to customize rails_admin navigation(side bar)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've been working on rails_admin and have many models in my project, In navigation all the models are displaying, need to scroll down for all models, So I want to display the models based on some group (main menu under that sub-menu's like in active admin). But rails_admin I don't find an option to that.I Need help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [rails_admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation), you can achieve grouping by using labels (non clickable) like so:

```
config.model 'Staff' do
   navigation_label 'Human Resources' # Every model with this 
   # navigation_label will be grouped under 'Human Resources'
   # More code here
end
```

[Screenshot example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCncg.png)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of rails_admin there is a config that promisses that is:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation

```
# Given there are the following models: League, Team and Division

config.model 'Team' do
  parent League
end

config.model 'Division' do
  parent League
end
```

I have a project with rails_admin but this option not working for me.

=(

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have tried this already its not I expected. In active admin there is option - menu :parent => "some name"  this will provide the drop-down approach to select sub menu, I want to implement this using rails_admin

Answer (score 0):

if you have many models, you can use rails concerns.

app/models/user.rb

```rb
class User
  include UserAdmin
end
```

app/models/concerns/user_admin.rb

```rb
module UserAdmin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rails_admin do
      # any code
    end
  end

end
```

app/models/avatar.rb

```rb
class Logo
  include AvatarAdmin
  end
end
```

app/models/concerns/avatar_admin.rb

```rb
module AvatarAdmin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rails_admin do
      parent User # <- this is the answer to the question
    end
  end

end
```

Now, navigation looks like this:

```
Users
  Avatars
```